# browser freezing when in while loop (snake game)

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm making the popular snake game for js homework.
I have a function which is meant to ensure that after an apple is eaten it moves to a different location on the canvas **while not being on any part of the snake**,
the function without the loop works fine (though apples are placed on the snake too):

```
 move() {
            let onSnake = true;
            let x = this.getRandomNumber(0, canvas.width - 1); //UnitSize);;
            let y = this.getRandomNumber(0, canvas.height - 1); //UnitSize);;
          
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

            this.draw();
        }
```

the function though with the loop ends up freezing after a few apples are eaten (right before hitting an apple):

```
 move() {
            let onSnake = true;
            let x = this.getRandomNumber(0, canvas.width - 1); //UnitSize);;
            let y = this.getRandomNumber(0, canvas.height - 1); //UnitSize);;
            while (onSnake) {
                onSnake = false;
                x = this.getRandomNumber(0, canvas.width - 1); //UnitSize);
                y = this.getRandomNumber(0, canvas.height - 1); //UnitSize);
                for (let index = 0; index < snake.parts.length; index++) {
                    if (x === snake.parts[index].x || y === snake.parts[index].y) {
                        onSnake = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

            this.draw();
        }
```

with getRandomNumber being:

```
getRandomNumber(min, max) {
            let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            r = r - (r % UnitSize);
            return r;
        }
```

this is my second question on SO, don't fry me please....

Comment: How long does the browser freeze? Forever? Or until a suitable position is found? The `if` where you check `x` and `y` against the snake parts uses `||` which means if the randomly selected location is in the same row OR in the same column as a snake part then it will set `onSnake` to true and try again. Depending on how big the snake is, that can blacklist the entire play space. Try `&&` and see if you get the result you want.

Comment: Corey and @DerykRich your right, my bad, dumb mistake, thanks for you patience, and thanks for the safety check,
should I take down this question being it's simpleness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't get a moment to test but I suspect it's as simple as the following evalutation.

```
if (x === snake.parts[index].x || y === snake.parts[index].y) {
    onSnake = true;
    break;
}
```

You are accepting either X **or** Y collision. Meaning the apple cannot share any X **or** Y coordinates with any of the snake pieces. What you want instead is **and** I believe. It's like saying we both live on the same house because we live on the same street. No, we need to also have the same address.

As a safety, you could add a limit to how many iterations of the loop can run in the event their is no more space remaining for an apple.

```
let counter = 0;
while (onSnake && counter < 5000) {
    onSnake = false;
    x = this.getRandomNumber(0, canvas.width - 1); //UnitSize);
    y = this.getRandomNumber(0, canvas.height - 1); //UnitSize);
    for (let index = 0; index < snake.parts.length; index++) {
        if (x === snake.parts[index].x && y === snake.parts[index].y) {
            onSnake = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    counter += 1;
}
if (counter == 5000)    {
    alert("Could not find space for any more apples!");
}
```

Comment: One additional improvement that can be made. Create an array of all of the free x/y locations. As the snake moves a step, remove the now taken x/y space and add the freed up x/y space. Then, perform your random on the list of free spaces to place the apple in one go. Once the array size has hit 0, it's clear the game is finished as there is nowhere else for an apple to be placed.

Comment: 100%, but in my case for each apple the snake eats it speeds up, so it's prob. impossible for the canvas to fill, also the snake detects self collision (as per the standard game mechanics) so filling it up to the max seems impossible for a player,
Thanks again!